# trying to fetch the select values from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am tring to access iframe element select and get its all value in my page, the select is actually inside a dialog.

My JS file i write this code to access select who's id is "firstSelectms2side__sx", but it didn't worked.

Ok let'sforget about iframe i tried this code it's the simple one where i tried to access the values of the select.

```
  <html>

  <head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="eRoster/jquery-1.9.1.js" ></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready( function () {
  $( "select" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
      });
   });
  </script>

  </head>

   <body>

   <select id="select">
   <option value="212"></option>
   <option value="243"></option>
   <option value="254"></option>
   <option value="263"></option>
   <option value="235"></option>
   <option value="233"></option>
   </select>

   </body>

   </html>
```

Also want to know when each() is being invoked.
It's doing nothing.

Comment: please share your html code.

Comment: is the frame served by the same domain as your page?

Comment: yes, i told earlier that i got the id of select, just because its in same domian. @Antoine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What u r doing is calling the each loop for select it should be for option, not select.

So just change it to option or just give the id of option.

```
$( "option" ).each(function( index );
```

also change .text() to val().

And if select is dynamically created then traverse down the select child and call each with reference to child of select.

Answer (score 1):

If you have iframe as below :-

```
<iframe id="iFrame" >
  <select id="firstSelectms2side__sx" multiple="multiple" size="6" name="firstSelectms2side__sx">
    <option value="M1018617">Amitkumar Gupta</option>
    <option value="M1003939">Lakshmi Rao</option>
    <option value="M1003423">M1003423</option>
    <option value="M1018652">M1018652</option>
    <option value="M1013712">Mahesh Kumar Kothapally</option>
    <option value="M1007327">Manikyam Pulaparthi</option>
    <option value="M1013240">Raghavendra S</option>
    <option value="M9002402">Shibi</option>
  </select>
</iframe>
```

Then in parent window :-

```
  var iframeBody = $("#iFrame").contents().find("body");

  var valueFromIframe = iContentBody.find($('#firstSelectms2side__sx option:selected')).text();
```

Comment: that's messy, and its not .text() but .val(), but here's +1 for the: $('#firstSelectms2side__sx option:selected')